# Refreshing Web.Config file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, refresh

I am using UrlRewriting module in one of my site, the site has 2 versions:

1. Desktop
2. Mobile

The code of the mobile version of the site resides in the desktop version only i.e if desktop version is in `c:\websites\[websitename]` then mobile site will be `c:\websites\[websitename]\mobile`

Now i have a utility to `add/modify/delete` the `vanity url's` from UI, so for the `vanity url's` i have created a seperate file known as `url.config` and linked it to the `web.config` file under `rewrite` node. whenever any new vanity has been added i update the database and then i update whole `url.config` file from the database and refresh the `web.config`.

Web.config refresh has been done like

```
Public Sub RefreshWebConfig()
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("web.config"))
    doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("web.config"))
 End Sub
```

The above code works as expected, it refreshes the `web.config` file and hence the added vanity gets live on the spot.

Now my client requires that the vanity should be updated to the mobile version also at the same time for the vanity added from the desktop version. So now what i am doing is i have created a seperate file under `mobile\urls.config` and also linked to `mobile\    web.config` file same as done for the desktop version.

Now i am using the below code to refresh mobile\web.config file like below:

```
Public Sub RefreshWebConfig()
   Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
   doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("web.config"))
   doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("web.config"))
   Dim doc1 As New XmlDocument()
   doc1.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/mobile/web.config"))
   doc1.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/mobile/web.config"))
End Sub
```

However it does not refreshes the `mobile\web.config` file with the above code because of the which i need to wait for around `5-10mins` or sometime even till `20mins` for the changes to reflect on the mobile site.

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this issue, and what could be its possible resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing this to trigger an application recycle so your site will reflect the changes you made?

As far as I know changing the `web.config` will trigger an app recycle at "some point"; not always right away, especially if the file that caused the trigger isn't required by the site for a while, in your case your `/mobile/web.config` may not be needed if a user doesn't visit the mobile page for a while. Your seeing the changes on your Desktop version right away because your root `web.config` was needed to load the page that you're viewing.

If you are doing this for a recycle, why not just recycle application instead touching the `web.config`.

If you wanted, you could simply force the site to restart by calling:

```
Public Sub RefreshWebConfig()
      HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
End Sub
```

More info on [HttpRuntime.UnLoadAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx)

Comment: that would be cool to recycle app pool directly, but can you tell how to recycle app pool of particular site, i have around 30 sites on a server...

Comment: Put that code in your site - it will restart that site, not the whole server.

Comment: I have one more concern, i want to recycle app pool of the mobile site, when there is any vanity addition from desktop version. Mobile site should automatically take effect when any new vanity has been added in desktop version.

Comment: From what I understand, they are actually the same website, just different URL for mobile/desktop. So run this code whenever you update any of your vanity URL's and you should be set - both desktop AND mobile will be updated right away because your site will restart. Why not try it first. Then if it doesn't work we can help more.....

Comment: No, the sites are different, i have 2 sites in IIS, www.abc.com and m.abc.com, whenever, there is any vanity addition in www.abc.com app pool of m.abc.com should also recycle... i want to achieve this

Comment: Is it a single admin for the 2 sites then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31199/discussion-between-abbas-and-darren)

Comment: i have admin to add vanities in the desktop version only, mobile version does not supports adding vanities, however any vanities added from the desktop version should also recycle mobile version.

Comment: sorry, i can't help any more. I don't understand enough about your setup.